# EXCEL 2016 - Cannot Use TEXT criteria in Conditional Formatting Rules

Tags: date, text, excel-2016

I have 3 columns. in the 1st i have ascending numbering, in the 2nd dates & 3rd text

I am trying fill in green color into a cell (of 1st column) which meets the following criteria:
the date is older than TODAY() and
contains specific text "text criteria"

in the conditional formatting rules window i tried the following:

```
=AND($M$6:$M$827<TODAY(); $O$6:$O$827="text criteria") 
=($M$6:$M$827<TODAY())*($O$6:$O$827="text criteria") 
=($M$6:$M$827<TODAY())+($O$6:$O$827="text criteria") 
=($M$6:$M$827<TODAY())&($O$6:$O$827="text criteria")
```

All occasions were received without error, however never got the highlight i need.
Because i was sure that the AND function is correct and should have worked i copied it into a 4th column and indeed it worked correctly in all 827 inputs.

On the other hand, i also used only the`$M$6:$M$827<TODAY()` part into the conditional formatting window and it work. But it also highlighted some entries should not have because it did not have the second criteria.

Is there a problem by using text criteria in conditional formatting? 
If yes how should i work around it? (I was thinking to use the newly 4th column; which works correctly; i need the entries that have the value "TRUE")

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: pnuts solution worked like a charm. to be fair to everybody i did not tried the other too solutions. sorry, no time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `;` is your delimiter and the column with ascending numbers is K and you wish to format K6:K827 when the value in the corresponding row for ColumnM is before today (but not blank) and the value in the corresponding row ColumnO is `text criteria`, please select K6:K827 clear any conditional formatting from those cells and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(M6<>"";M6<TODAY();O6="text criteria")
```

with green fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You would only use the upper cell of the columns, making the row relative:

```
=AND($M6<TODAY(); $O6 ="text criteria")
```

Then make the Applies To: `$M$6:$M$827` this should include all the rows and column you desire to apply the conditional formatting.

[image: ![enter image description here]